# Communicate between two instances vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 separate vue js instances. I need to pass a value from one instance to another instance. which i can pass but can't bind that value in a model.This is how i am passing info from one instance to another

```
var holiday = new Vue({});
```

Emitting value from one instance

```
holiday.$emit('holiday_id',{
    holiday_id : response.data.id
});
```

Receiving holiday id whenever second instance is mounted. After that can't bind that value in a model

```
mounted() {
    holiday.$on('holiday_id', function(holiday){
        this.temp_holiday_id = holiday.holiday_id;
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a regular function in the callback for the event listener. So `this` does not point to the vue instance and thats the reason you can't access and modify `this.temp_holiday_id`
in your data property

So use an arrow function so that `this` is bound lexically

```
mounted() {
    holiday.$on('holiday_id', (holiday) => {
        this.temp_holiday_id = holiday.holiday_id;
    });
}
```

or set `var self = this` in the mounted hook so the callback has a closure over `self` pointing the vue instance

```
mounted() {
    var self = this;
    holiday.$on('holiday_id', function(holiday){
        self.temp_holiday_id = holiday.holiday_id;
    });
}
```